# Jail outgoing DNS queries to single group with iptables does not work

Tags: permissions, iptables, dns, firewall, hardening

I am trying to block all DNS queries from my machine by default, and only allow them for specific group of users. I try these rules:

```
sudo su
groupadd dns-allowed
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m owner --gid-owner dns-allowed -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j REJECT
```

With the second, DNS queries are blocked successfully, but then i try to launch ping`` within `dns-allowed` group, DNS queries still blocked:

```
sudo sg dns-allowed "ping google.com"
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

I noticed that if i use `nslookup` instead of ping with specifying DNS server 8.8.8.8 works when launched withing `dns-allowed` group, but just as `ping` fails, **most of applications still cannot use DNS within it**:

```
sudo sg dns-allowed "nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8"
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: ....
```

**resolv.conf**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: What are the contents of /etc/resolv.conf? It might be that you are running a local nameserver and that all the external requests are coming from  a daemon.

Comment: @icarus surprisely it points to the `nameserver 127.0.1.1` however my networkmanager connection has DNS server 8.8.8.8 configured. I am lost with this. It's ubuntu.

Comment: @icarus I removed dnsmasq and it now points to google DNS, however, problem is not gone with `ping`, `curl`, only `nslookup` is working.

Comment: So you probably are running systemd-resolve (the 127.0.0.53 server). For example if you run `ping google.com` then `ping` will use the C library routines like gethostbyname to get the address. This will typically use /etc/nsswitch.conf to guide it into loading additional shared libraries which do the lookup. You should probably run nslookup in its interactive mode and use the `server` command to know exactly where you are sending queries, or maybe use `dig` instead.